# List of indices to data.table

Tags: r, list, data.table

assuming the subsequent list of vectors,

```
ll <- structure(list(
    `007` = NULL, `1908` = 2L, `1934` = NULL, `1948` = NULL, `333` = 4L, baloni = 17L, abate = 19L, abatjour = 18L, abbacchio = 20:32, abbeveraggio = 33L),
    .Names = c("007", "1908", "1934", "1948", "333", "abaloni", "abate", "abatjour", "abbacchio", "abbeveraggio"
))
```

where each of them represent a set of positions (i.e., indices).

What is a fast and smart way to create a `data.table` in which each row contains the name of the list to which the corresponding position belongs to?

So, for the previous object `ll` the result would be the following:

```
              V1
 1:           NA
 2:         1908
 3:           NA
 4:          333
 5:           NA
 6:           NA
 7:           NA
 8:           NA
 9:           NA
10:           NA
11:           NA
12:           NA
13:           NA
14:           NA
15:           NA
16:           NA
17:      abaloni
18:     abatjour
19:        abate
20:    abbacchio
21:    abbacchio
22:    abbacchio
23:    abbacchio
24:    abbacchio
25:    abbacchio
26:    abbacchio
27:    abbacchio
28:    abbacchio
29:    abbacchio
30:    abbacchio
31:    abbacchio
32:    abbacchio
33: abbeveraggio
```

Some considerations:

- list children do not have same length
- positions that do not exists have to be filled with `NA` values

I think the solution approach mainly consists of reverting the structure of the list (indices vs terms) but I was not able at the time to reach a solution.

Some help or advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
# create matirx
mat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(ll), function(x) 
  if (!is.null(ll[[x]]))cbind(ll[[x]], names(ll)[x])))

# create index
idx <- as.integer(mat[, 1])

# create vector
vec <- rep(NA_character_, max(idx))
vec[idx] <- mat[, 2]

# create data.table
library(data.table)
data.table(V1 = vec)
```

The result:

```
             V1
 1:           NA
 2:         1908
 3:           NA
 4:          333
 5:           NA
 6:           NA
 7:           NA
 8:           NA
 9:           NA
10:           NA
11:           NA
12:           NA
13:           NA
14:           NA
15:           NA
16:           NA
17:      abaloni
18:     abatjour
19:        abate
20:    abbacchio
21:    abbacchio
22:    abbacchio
23:    abbacchio
24:    abbacchio
25:    abbacchio
26:    abbacchio
27:    abbacchio
28:    abbacchio
29:    abbacchio
30:    abbacchio
31:    abbacchio
32:    abbacchio
33: abbeveraggio
              V1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just loop through your list and use `set`:

```
d = data.table(rep(NA_character_, max(sapply(ll, max))))

for (i in seq_along(ll))
  if (!is.null(ll[[i]])) set(d, ll[[i]], 1L, names(ll)[i])
```